# Latex template for making slide presentation

Tags: beamer, errors, slideshow

I am trying to prepare a slide in LaTeX for presentation but couldn't. I am writing the following code but it failed to run due to errors:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Sample tittle}
\subtitle{sample}
\begin{document}
\frame{
\titlepage
}
\frame{
\frametitle{sample page 1}
\[\frac{-b}{a}]
}
\frame{
\frametitle{sample page 2}
\framesubtitle{an example}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 1
\item 3
\end{itemize}
}
\frame{
\frametitle{paragraph content}
this is a paragraph
}
\end{document}.
```

Comment: Please replace `\[\frac{-b}{a}]` by `\[\frac{-b}{a}\]`. (The closing `\]` misses the backslash.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `]` which should be a `\]` after `\frac{-b}{a}`. I would really use the frame as an environment, i.e. `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Sample tittle}
\subtitle{sample}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{sample page 1}
\[\frac{-b}{a}\]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{sample page 2}
\framesubtitle{an example}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 1
\item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{paragraph content}
this is a paragraph
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot I don't get the reference number. I have more than two pages of reference but the reference number doesn't appear and citations do dot give the desired reference. What command should i add in order to get desired reference number in the text?

Comment: @gete There is no reference in the code as far as I can see. If you have a new question with a new code, you may just ask a new question, which is free. (I will decouple now for a while anyway..)